# Postgresql Replication issues of clarity

Tags: postgresql, replication

In an effort to document myself I examined a few sources; [these](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-replication.html) two [from the official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-quick-setup.html) and this [external one seemed promising](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-a-hot-standby-with-postgresql)

Now the latter one seems to be updated in 2020, but refers to version 9.2  which is somewhat dated [*angst emoji*].  There are some discrepancies I want to clear up.

• my understanding is that a hot-standby is open for read-only SQL statements.  However the defaults for postgresql.conf on version 12 are:
`#wal_level = replica                        # minimal, replica, or logical`
while the [docs for version 12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-replication.html) states  `wal_level must be set to replica or higher to allow connections from standby servers` not `hot_standby`  as is alluded to the external reference. So `hot_standby`is not longer a valid value?  But to further the confusion, I have not found what distinguishes a `replica` from a `logical` replication, just [logical adds information necessary to support logical decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-wal.html)

•  The [quick setup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/logical-replication-quick-setup.html) feels too 'quick' for my tastes.  While it tracks pretty much the external source... what's missing from the 'quick' approach?

• I also have had difficulty in searching the docs for how the replica should be configured.  How to determine whether as server is hot or warm?

*note: I realise this is not a single question, but the issues are still part of the object of configuring a main db and a replica db*

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up things from *logical* and *WAL* (physical) replication, which adds to the confusion. Despite being both called "replication", these have quite different mechanisms and require different configuration. Depending on the kind of replication you want to set up, you should refer to the appropriate section of the documentation.

`wal_level` is set on the primary and determines the amount of information written to the WAL. The `replica` value causes more information to be written than `minimal`, and `logical` more information yet.

> In releases prior to 9.6, this parameter also allowed the values `archive` and `hot_standby`. These are still accepted but mapped to replica

In contrast, `hot_standby` *parameter* (not the `wal_level` *value*) only affects the replica because it changes the replica behaviour. The distinction between "hot" and "warm" only applies to physical standby servers, as they are in a continuous recovery state, accepting and applying WAL records from the primary. A database would not normally be accessible in this state, but setting `hot_standby = on` allows you limited (read only) access.

Logical replicas are always "hot" in the sense that the receiving databases are in the fully operational state.

Comment: very helpful.  Thus with the goal of having a read-only replica, my understanding now is : replication with `wal_level = logical` on the main DB. The application's middleware will direct read requests to the replica, thus the latter does not have to bother with setting `hot_standby = on `, though that could be conceived as an additional layer to impede writing to the replica.  Correct?

Comment: You're still confusing logical and physical replication; which one do you want?

Comment: Yes that is quite possible. My grasp is that one wants a physical replica to take over in case the main one goes down. That is not a requirement per se. So logical should be fine as it has better performance.  But it is my understanding that the logical one can take over master role with additional parameter modifications. Correct?